# configure bus for nservicebus 4.x?

Tags: c#, service, nservicebus

I just upgraded to nservicebus 4.x and I am trying to get instance of a bus to an endpoint using configure.with() but it goes into infinite loop and says timeout.

```
var bus = Configure.WIth()
     .DefineEndpoint("nservicebus.handler.x");
```

I tried multiple things like getting all assemblies and only scanning which are needed but it didn't help.

Comment: Curious, why not update to v5?

Comment: Where are you executing this code from?

Comment: I am executing inside a web service.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are calling `Configure.WIth()` from. Also have you looked at the samples ?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it, pause the execution? Calling this method is quite common and it never creates any issues. There must be something else.

Comment: Are you using RavenDb in your application, per chance?